# GCP Composer (Autoscaling) environment error - "Some of the GKE pods failed to become healthy"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine

We created Beta Autoscaling composer in GCP. Which failed creating tne environment. We used all default values when creating the environment.

[image]

We did not find any resources on correcting this. We are pretty new to this.

When creating Normal Composer, it is working without any issues.

Service account we used is default Compute engine account.

Answer (score 1):

Detailed error logs has not been provided, but I'm assuming that your node is failing to send hearbeats updating their Health status to the Master. This causing Node fail to become healthy.
This problem occurs when the egress is not allowed by the default on the VPC.

GKE actually does not create any egress firewall rules upon cluster creation, however GKE assumes nodes are allowed to egress to any destination by default.

Kindly check Firewall Rules for denial of egress.

By default GCP creates a firewall rule of allowing all egress. If the customer deletes the rule or denies all egress, then they must configure a firewall rule that allows egress on the master CIDR block via tcp ports 443, 10250. [Private Cluster Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#add_firewall_rules) documents how to obtain the master CIDR block.

If you enable other GKE Add-Ons this may require adding additional egress firewall rules.

For furher GKE Autoscaling reference you may refer on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler#enabling_autoscaling_for_an_existing_node_pool)